# dynamically show button when a value changes

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-recordeditform

I'm iterating over a list of Cases and displaying a lightning-record-edit-form for each Case. I want to dynamically show/hide a save button at the end of each row if a value is changed in that row. And/or a save all button display that will save all changes. I'd need the Case Id and changes on each case.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to do this?

.js

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getCases from '@salesforce/apex/CaseController.getCases';

export default class EditableDatatable extends LightningElement {

    cases = [];
    editTable = true;
    buttonVisible = false;
    @wire(getCases)
    listOfCases({data, error}) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('data------', JSON.stringify(data));
            this.cases = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else {
            console.log('error------', error);

            this.cases = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log('event.detail --- ', JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        console.log('event.detail.Id --- ', event.detail.Id);
        console.log('event.detail.name --- ', event.detail.name);
    }
}
```

.HTML

```
        <template for:each={cases} for:item="c">
            <div key={c.Id}>
                <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" record-id={c.Id}>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-12 slds-border_bottom"><lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="CaseNumber"></lightning-output-field></div>
                        <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_bottom"><lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChange} id={c.Id} name="ContactId" field-name="ContactId" value={c.ContactId}></lightning-input-field></div>
                        <div class="slds-size_4-of-12 slds-border_bottom"><lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="Subject" value={c.Subject}></lightning-input-field></div>
                        <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_bottom"><lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChange} id={c.Id} name="Priority"  field-name="Priority" value={c.Priority}></lightning-input-field></div>
                        <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-border_bottom"><lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="Status" value={c.Status}></lightning-input-field></div>
                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-12"><template if:true={buttonVisible}><lightning-button class="slds-var-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Save"></lightning-button></template></div>
                    </div>
                </lightning-record-edit-form>
            </div>
        </template>
```

apex

```
public with sharing class CaseController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Case> getCases() {
        try {
            System.debug('-----getCases----- ');
            List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Priority, Subject, Status, ContactId FROM Case LIMIT 5];
            System.debug('caseList----- '+caseList);
            return caseList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to accomplish this in the handleChange call but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I would mention to use the [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) component in this context instead of rendering this complicated list of record edit forms. The standard datatable component has an ability to perform inline editing and dynamically show save button which can save all records at once instead of doing it one by one.

In case you're willing to proceed with the current implementation, you can bind record to each input element in your form like this, using [data-*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_accessibility_attributes) bindings

```
<lightning-output-field data-id={c.Id} variant="label-hidden" field-name="CaseNumber">
</lightning-output-field>
```

do the same to your button.

```
 <lightning-button data-id={c.Id} class="slds-var-m-top_small slds-hide" type="submit" label="Save">
```

and finally, you can modify your handleChange function like this

```
  handleChange(event) {
    try {
      const recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      console.log("lightning-button[data-id='" + recordId + "']");
      if (recordId) {
        const button = this.template.querySelector(
          "lightning-button[data-id='" + recordId + "']"
        );
        if (button) {
          button.classList.remove("slds-hide");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

and after all, you will be faced with the problem where each input field handles changes differently, not only on onchange event, and this solution will work only for the first column, and you will and up with writing different on change implementations. therefore, I would again suggest going with the [lightning-datatable](https://ttps://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) component from the component library which does all this for you.